# Customized Lightning-modal header

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-modal

Is there anyway to customize the lightning-modal-header in lwc? If I leave out the label and just use the subheader. I get this error message.

[image]

However the label only takes in a string while I want my header to look like this [image]

I can do this either by having this code in the subheader, or just in the body, I'm not sure if there was a better way to do this though (It seems to use the lightning-modal I need to supply a label for the header) It seems I can do this without using LightningModal, but I wanted to see if it was possible to do it with the build in component as well.